# How good is the free comcast wireless router?

Tags: networking, router

Comcast will give their customers a free wireless router. To get this router you browse to

http://www.comcast.com/wirelessrouter

and order one.

Does anyone have any experience with this router? Is it any good? Does anyone have any specific model numbers for the routers they give out?

My definition of good--

Strong enough to cover about a .25 acre plot of land, easily configured, easy to tinker with, worry free, good performance. Ideally I'd like to set something up, get good signal coverage through the house, and forget it even exists until I want to play with it.

We have about a half dozen devices that need wifi access.

Comment: I don't know that particular router, but those things are so inexpensive now, I can't see why it would be so much poorer than anything else. Someone who will read the specs will probably have more info.

Answer (score 1):

I got a free wifi router from Comcast two months ago (7/2010) but it may have been a different make/model. They sent me a D-Link DIR-601 and it was utterly pathetic, unusable unless I sat next to it.

Answer (score 0):

What is your definition of good? fits your basic needs? then probably. Its just like any other home grade router really. Don't expect it to handle wireless for a shopping mall food court or anything, but for use in a normal sized home, sure, its fine.

Comment: updated question with my definition of good.